# redirect flask logs to Gunicorn output

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, amazon-cloudwatch

In order to be able to access the `Flask API` logs inside `AWS CloudWatch Logs`, I added the following configuration to `Flask` App:

```
from logging.config import dictConfig
# loggings
dictConfig( {
    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {'default': {
        'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s in %(module)s: %(message)s',
    }},
    'handlers': {
        'wsgi': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout',
            'formatter': 'default'
        }
    },
    'root': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'handlers': ['wsgi']
    }
} )
```

Flask App is deployed on an `Nginx server`. That worked fin on `nginx` until I added `Gunicorn` behind it because I couldn't make multiple requests at the same time:

```
gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 --workers=5 api:app
```

But then after adding `Gunicorn`, I no longer get the logs of the application in `CloudWatch Logs` and This is all I get:

```
[2018-10-04 12:48:25 +0000] [7] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
12:48:25
[2018-10-04 12:48:25 +0000] [7] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (7)
12:48:25
[2018-10-04 12:48:25 +0000] [7] [INFO] Using worker: sync
12:48:25
[2018-10-04 12:48:25 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
12:48:25
[2018-10-04 12:48:25 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
12:48:25
[2018-10-04 12:48:25 +0000] [12] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12
12:48:25
[2018-10-04 12:48:25 +0000] [13] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 13
12:48:25
[2018-10-04 12:48:25 +0000] [14] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 14
```

My question is: how to redirect the application logs to `Gunicorn` ?

Answer (score 2):

https://medium.com/@trstringer/logging-flask-and-gunicorn-the-manageable-way-2e6f0b8beb2f

By Default, gunicorn logs are set at warning. So, you need to check and update the gunicorn level.